# Selecting the first nth rows by group with number of rows varied

Tags: r, dataframe

I like to select the first (2,3,0,4) rows of each group in a data frame.

```
> f<-data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4),y=c(1:7))
> 
>   group y
>      1 1
>      1 2
>      1 3
>      2 4
>      2 5
>      3 6
>      4 7
```

and obtain a data frame as follows

```
group y
1 1
1 2
2 4
2 5
4 7
```

I tried to use `by` and `head` but head does not take a vector.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version of function with indexes.

```
fun1 <- function(){
  idx <- c(0,which(diff(f$group)!=0))+1
  idx2 <- unlist(lapply(1:length(nf),function(x)  seq.int(from=idx[x],length.out=nf[x])),use.names=F)
  f1 <- f[idx2,]
  return(f1)
}

fun2 <- function(){
  ddply(f,.(group),function(x) head(x,nf[x[1,1]]))
}
```

Test data (size suggested by author of question)

```
f<-data.frame(group=sample(1:1000,50000,T),y=c(1:50000))
f <- f[order(f$group),]
nf <- rpois(length(unique(f$group)),3)
```

system.time(fun1())
   system.time(fun2())

On my system ~60 times faster is fun1.

Comment: I test your code with my dataset and indeed it is very fast. For ddply, I get the following error message `Error in if (n < 0L) max(nrow(x) + n, 0L) else min(n, nrow(x)) :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Probably you have missing values in group variable. You can recode missing to some value or use na.omit(f).

Answer (score 5):

With the more traditional `lapply`:

```
k <- c(2,3,0,4)
fs <- split(f, f$group)
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(k), function(i) head(fs[[i]], k[i])))
```

result is:

```
  group y
1     1 1
2     1 2
4     2 4
5     2 5
7     4 7
```

Comment: I almost submitted nearly the same code... again.  We think _very_ similarly.

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks for the compliment.  I've appreciated your many helpful answers here.  By the way, I saw I was faster than you earlier today only because you edited the question first -- thanks for taking the time to make the questions better too.

Comment: Neat way of doing it. I have a large data frame about 50K categories in the group. Any idea how fast this is. Cheers

Comment: @Tony: Hard to say; I believe the `split` will make a new data object, if that's true and `f` is very large, that could take a while.  If it proves too slow, Hadley's `plyr` package supposedly does some things like this faster, you could try that (as in Sacha's solution).  If you only want a couple rows from each group, it's also entirely possible that a carefully written for loop could improve on this.  Another possibility is simplifying the `split`, as only the `y` needs to be kept around, but that complicates the bookkeeping.

Answer (score 2):

Using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
rows <- c(2,3,0,4)
ddply(f,.(group),function(x)head(x,rows[x[1,1]]))
        group y
    1     1 1
    2     1 2
    3     2 4
    4     2 5
    5     4 7
```

## edit:

misunderstood the question so updated answer